# Sum of Two CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

how to get sum of two CGRect

```
CGRect requiredFirst = [firstName boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

CGRect requiredLast = [lastName boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
```

CGRect height  = ???

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what you're looking for - how should these 2 rects be combined?

Comment: requiredFirst.size.height + requiredLast.size.height;

Comment: @KkMIW: OK - you've just defined exactly the answer of the sum of heights of two rects. If you knew this already then why have you asked the question?

Comment: The height property would be a CGFloat, not a CGRect.

Comment: I can't give you an answer because the question is closed, but the answer is in geometry.h, where there are a number of nice little functions, the one you want is CGRectUnion(rect1, rect2) which returns the smallest rect that contains rect1 & rect2.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectUnion

Comment: @Jef keep in mind that CGRectUnion will give a very different answer than the one provided by the accepted answer (and that answer doesn't seem useful at all).

Comment: heh, yup. Maybe even a result with some applications..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a method that will do that:

```
- (CGRect)combineFrames:(CGRect)frame1, f2:(CGRect)frame2{
    CGFloat x = frame1.origin.x + frame2.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = frame1.origin.y + frame2.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = frame1.size.width + frame2.size.width;
    CGFloat height = frame1.size.height + frame2.size.height;

    CGRect combinedFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    return combinedFrame;
}
```

This method just adds all four of the frame's aspects (x, y, width, height) together individually then reconstructs it and returns it.
Use it like this:

```
CGRect combinedFrame = [self combineFrames:requiredFirst, f2:requiredLast];
CGFloat height = combinedFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: When would this be useful? I can't think of when anyone would need this calculation.

Comment: @rmaddy Maybe he wants to insert one border of two rects.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum of the heights:

```
CGFloat height = requiredFirst.size.height + requiredLast.size.height;
```

Comment: some times after posting question, i do get answer for my question.

Comment: @KkMIW Next time, take a few more minutes to think about what you're asking and see if you can come up with the solution on your own before posting a question then. Come to StackOverflow after you know you can't answer your own question :)

Comment: Shouldn't `height` be `CGFloat`, not `CGRect`?

Comment: Woops, you're right @rmaddy. I was basing it off OP's question and didn't think twice about the data type